# Acesso aos dados no DAL com ASP.Net MVC Identity e Owin

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, owin

Hoje minha solução tem um projeto de aplicação Web MVC 5 e uma Library de DAL (Data Access Layer) com EF DatabaseFirst.

Quero criar uma camada com MVC Identity + Owin, no entanto, gostaria que o acesso aos dados fossem feitos no DAL.

Como eu faço isso? Tem algum bom exemplo que fale como separar o acesso aos dados do MVC Identity e Owin?

Comment: Tem certeza de que quer fazer isso? Olha, até vou responder, mas não recomendo você seguir por este caminho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar, ASP.NET Identity e OWIN não são "separáveis". [OWIN é um padrão de interface](http://owin.org/), e o ASP.NET Identity é uma implementação que lida com usuários na sua aplicação. O ASP.NET Identity pode ou não seguir o OWIN, porque trabalha com ele, mas pode usar outro padrão também, sem problemas.

Em segundo lugar, para reimplementar o comportamento do ASP.NET Identity, você terá que reimplementar as seguintes classes:

- [`UserManager`](https://www.symbolsource.org/MyGet/Metadata/aspnetwebstacknightly/Project/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/2.0.0-rtm-140226/Release/Default/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/UserManager.cs?ImageName=Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core)
- [`SignInManager`](http://www.symbolsource.org/MyGet/Metadata/aspnetwebstacknightly/Project/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin/2.2.0-alpha1-140723/Release/Default/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin/SignInManager.cs?ImageName=Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin)
- [`RoleManager` (opcional, se seu sistema usa Roles)](https://www.symbolsource.org/MyGet/Metadata/aspnetwebstacknightly/Project/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/2.0.0-beta1-140209/Release/Default/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/RoleManager.cs?ImageName=Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core)

Feito isso, seu sistema poderá trabalhar com o ASP.NET Identity a nível de DAL.

O problema é que colocando uma camada a mais você estará criando um complicador, visto que a aplicação é implementada usando um modelo agnóstico de acesso a dados com ligação dinâmica a bibliotecas como o Entity Framework.

Comment: Olá Cigano. Desculpa se não fui claro, mas não pretendo separar o Identity do Owin. Só quero centralizar o acesso aos dados na camada de acesso a dados. Não seria uma boa prática?

Comment: O problema é que colocando uma camada a mais você está criando um complicador, visto que a aplicação é implementada usando um modelo agnóstico de acesso a dados com ligação dinâmica a bibliotecas como o Entity Framework.

Comment: Por eu estar trabalhando com uma camada de acesso a dados separada da minha aplicação principal e o Identity já vem com alguns padrões próprio de acessos, eu desconfiava que estava de fato criando um complicador, mas nada melhor que ouvir outras opiniões. Vlw.